# Asp.net project structure in svn

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, .net

We have a Asp.net webforms webapplication. The solution has the following structure:

> - MySolution\
>
>   - MySolution.Main\
>   - MySolution.Web\
>   - MySolution.sln

Is there a best practice how to structure the trunk directory? Put the solution directory in the trunk or the content of the solution direcotry? Build a new structure under trunk?

---

**Edit:**

I think I take the following structure:

```
trunk\
    doc\
    lib\
    src\
       MySolution.Main\
       MySolution.Web\
    Mysolution.sln
```

In this case I have the sln file directly under the trunk. Is that a good idea?

Comment: We successfully use the structure proposed in the accepted answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661845/working-directory-structure-for-svn-visual-studio-repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put it in a separate directory, calling it `src\` for example. Like this you can create additional directories for documentation and other stuff.

**Example:**

```
trunk\
  src\
    MySolution.Main\
    MySolution.Web\
    MySolution.sln
  doc\
```

**Suggestion:**
Take a look at http://codeplex.com, it might be a reference point on how some popular projects are structured.

Answer (score 0):

we were faced with this dilema and what we did is pretty much what you have done. We did not start out this way we had a massive solution that needed seperating out into products.

And after we had done that and got rid of the chaff we found we were left with a structure much like you are describing, he had a directory called src under trunc and then the structure you describe

One thing to watch is do not commit bin or .suo files these are generated each time and it is a mistake to commit them.

Don't whatever you do invent a totally new structure stick with the standard trunk, tags, branches structure as this is most definately best practise.